# Magento 2.1.8 database move to another installation

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I've tried to move my Magento database to the another fresh Magento installation.
So in Plesk panel, I've created MySQL dump and save on my HDD and then imported this to new installation but after that, I have no names on my category also can't see Products when you click on catalog (security reason can't see this page).

There are about 1800 Products. How can I perhaps transfer just Products Categories and Attributes to the new installation?

Old Installation:
There was migration database from 1.9 to 2.1 and it looks like this migration wasn't perfect.